# Using python to solve for value that meets a condition

Tags: python, list, loops, hash, solver

new true value that meets the condition = v

previous true value = vprev

I am trying to look for a v so that hash of str(((power(v,2))+(power(vprev, 3))) begins with ee

I tried this

```
import hashlib
values_list = []# a list where v and prev will be
solved = False
v = 1 # to start looping from 1

while not solved:
    for index, v in enumerate(values_list):
        vprev = values_list[(index - 1)]
    results = str(v**2 + vprev**3)
    results_encoded = results.encode()
    results_hashed = hashlib.sha256(results_encoded).hexdigest()
    if results[0:2] == "ee":
        solved = True
        values_list.append(v)
    else: v += 1

print(values_list)
```

I'm expecting a list with the first true value but I have failed

Comment: Thanks John. Apologies, I'm new at Python. I have tried researching for a solution and failed. I have made edits as you've recommended. Any further advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Commenting your own code:

```py
# ...
solved = False
v = 1 # to start looping from 1

while solved:
    # This block is never executed: the `while` condition-check fails since the initial state of `solved` is `False`

print(values_list)
```

you'll probably want to use `while not solved:` instead

Comment: Thank you Adam, I've changed this. Could you please look at it again

Comment: So the initial question was answered - you should select a `best` answer, then ask a new question. Also, in your update, you mention your desired output, but not what the code above is giving you...